# Extra HASH() reference added to Perl hash output

Tags: perl, hash

I'm trying to read a FORTRAN program using Perl, and remove an `INCLUDE` command and replace it with a `USE`.

This is working great, except when printing out the contents of the hash storing the existing `USE` statements, I get an extra entry.

```
my @lines = ( );
my %uses = { };

foreach $f1line (<>) {
    $f1line =~ s/\r[\n]*//g;

    if ($f1line =~ /^\s*INCLUDE 'FILE1.CMN'/ ||
        $f1line =~ /^\s*INCLUDE 'FILE2.CMN'/ ||
        $f1line =~ /^\s*INCLUDE 'FILE3.CMN'/) {
            $f1line = "      USE My_Mod";
    }

    if ($f1line =~ /^\s*USE /) {
        $uses{$f1line} = 1;
    }

    push @lines, $f1line . $/;
}

$found = 0;

foreach $line (@lines) {
    if ($found == 0 && $line =~ /^\s*USE /) {
        foreach my $x (sort(keys(%uses))) {
            print $x . $/;                      # (1)
        }

        $found = 1;
    } elsif ($found == 1 && $line =~ /^\s*USE /) {
        next;
    } else {
        print $line;
    }
}
```

The output is this:

```
C     Include parameters here
      USE My_Mod
      USE MyOther_Mod
      USE EvenAnother_Mod
HASH(0x7f9dc3805ce8)
```

Where is the `HASH(0x...)` reference coming from? The only place I'm printing the contents of the hash is on line `(1)`. It almost looks like iterating over the keys of the hash is somehow including the hash itself.

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: You should start every Perl file with `use strict; use warnings;`. That would have found at least one error in your code.

Comment: Hint: It's not the hash itself (you could have checked that by printing `\%uses`); it's coming right from the beginning: `my %uses = { };`

Comment: There's no point in using `$/` there. If you haven't changed it yourself, it contains `"\n"`.

Comment: `.` is a metacharacter in regexes and needs to be escaped if you want to match it literally.

Comment: Strongly consider not using global variables everywhere.

Comment: `[\n]` is better written as `\n` in a regex.

Comment: @melpomene: Thanks, clearly it's been a LONG time since I've written any Perl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not really having a big problem, the big deal here is that you are not able to see the errors you are doing.

That's why you should always [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html)

In your code you start with:

```
my %uses = { };
```

When it should be:

```
my %uses = ();
```

or

```
my %uses; #it's fine also
```

And then it will works.

By using `{}` in a "hash" context you could create a [hashref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References) which is not the case.

> A reference to an anonymous hash can be created using curly brackets:
>
> ```
>     $hashref = {
>         'Adam'  => 'Eve',
>         'Clyde' => 'Bonnie',
>     };
> ```

Also is a good practice declare your variables in `foreach` loop like:

```
foreach my $line (@lines) {
```

And in the rest of your code.

Comment: Thanks! So obviously I haven't done Perl in 10+ years; has the declaration of an empty hash changed? I could have sworn it once required curly-braces; regular round parens were only to be used for list initialization.

Comment: By the way it hasn't changed, using round parens creates a regular hash key/value like %hash = ( a => 1, b=>2).

Comment: @Tenner Initializing a hash is done with a list (of alternating key/value elements). But declaring an empty hash doesn't require initialization at all: `my %hash;` is fine.